# Extract number from image with 2D array using Python tesseract

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, tesseract

During extract Integers from a image containing a 2D Matrix form Tesseract is unable to give the correct result and the result varies every time we execute the code can anybody please give some idea what is missing  from the code below

```
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
rows = img.shape[0]
cols = img.shape[1]

#print rows , cols

img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply dilation and erosion to remove some noise
#kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint64)
#img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
#img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)

# Write image after removed noise

cv2.imwrite(src_path + "removed_noise1.png", img)

#  Apply threshold to get image with only black and white
#img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,225,95)
img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C , cv2.THRESH_BINARY ,251,95)
#print cv2.getGaussianKernel(ksize=221,sigma=41)

# Write the image after apply opencv to do some ...
cv2.imwrite(src_path + "thres1.png", img)

# Recognize text with tesseract for python  
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(src_path + "thres1.png"))
```

**Input**

[image]

Threshold value : adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C , cv2.THRESH_BINARY ,251,95

Output of threshold :
[image]

Output is in the form of 1 5 5 7 5 7 3 8 6 4 9 0 2 4 8 6 1 3 0 2 3 9 0 8 9 can be either in the row major form and column major form doesn't matter but we do need the given output saved into a variable

Comment: Can you upload some sample input images along with their adaptive threshold outputs ?

Comment: I have attached the input file

Comment: Did you accidentally post the same picture again?

Comment: And what is the expected output? You have a grid in this image, in which format are you expecting output ?

Comment: Output is in the form of  1 5 5 7 5
                                       7 3 8 6 4
                                       9 0 2 4 8
                                       6 1 3 0 2 
                                       3 9 0 8 9  can be either in the row major form and column major form doesn't matter but we do need the given output saved into a variable

Comment: Yes, i have accidentally added two images, Now removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the threshold value from 251, 95 to something like 251, 40.

```
img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C , cv2.THRESH_BINARY ,251,40)
```

It seems you already have perfect image which doesn't require any changes to extract string from image. Pytesseract's image_to_string doesn't work on my system so I used someone's made word by word OCR. This is definitely not the best solution in the world by hey if it works, it works. I have attached few files (see google drive links below)

**Steps:**

1. Run slice_img.py : this will break your image into 5x5 pieces.
2. Run TrainAndTest.py : this will extract numbers from each slice of
   image we have created and save it to data.txt file.

**Please note:**

1. Training_chars.png, classifications.txt and flattened_images.txt
   are files necessary for OCR to work.
2. You must have numpy, PIL, OpenCV libraries installed for the above
   script to work
3. Please keep all files provided in same folder and use image name as
   test.png

TrainAndTest.py - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B05aeuFExe2Aa3p3SWszN2xqU2c/view?usp=sharing

slice_image.py - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B05aeuFExe2AN0t3UUlGZ3VjcW8/view?usp=sharing

training_chars.png - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B05aeuFExe2ANjJNbzV5VTJyRTA/view?usp=sharing

classifications.txt - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B05aeuFExe2AZU91bUpOblB3d2c/view?usp=sharing

flattened_images.txt - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B05aeuFExe2AeXVnbXVXVTZ2RTQ/view?usp=sharing